# How to make hexdump not wait for 16 characters from stdin to display their hex values?

Tags: linux, terminal, hexdump

If I opened `hexdump` without any argument in the terminal:

```
hexdump
```

When I type something in the terminal and press `Enter`, `hexdump` will display the hex values for whatever characters I type.

But `hexdump` will only display the hex values if I type 16 characters, for example:

[image]

Here, I typed the character `a` 15 times and I pressed `Enter`(so `hexdump` received 16 characters (15`a` + `\n`)).

But if I type less than 16 characters, for example:

[image]

Here, I typed the character `a` 14 times and I pressed `Enter`(so `hexdump` received 15 characters (14`a` + `\n`)). And in this case `hexdump` did not display anything.

Can I make `hexdump` display the hex values for whatever length of characters it receives instead of it waiting for 16 characters to be received?

**Note**: I do not want to "*use options both for hexdump and xxd to display one byte as hex per line*" (as suggested in a comment here). What I want to do basically is for example to know what the hex value for A without having to type an extra 15 characters to get it.

Comment: IIRC output lines are buffered by default, not sure ATM if you can change that from the shell. But you can use options both for `hexdump` and `xxd` to display one byte as hex per line, would that be acceptable?

Comment: Try `hexdump -v -e '/1 "%02X\n"'`. Then you only have to type `A` and return to know the hex value for `A`. You still have to type return, because the shell buffers the input line. `man ascii` also works. :-)

Comment: Unneeded screenshots are evil, please use text copy-paste if it is possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `hexdump -v -e '/1 "%02X\n"'`. That displays one hex byte per line, so the line output buffering won't stop the line from being displayed.

Then you only have to type A and return to know the hex value for A. You still have to type return, because the shell buffers also does line buffering on the input.

`man ascii` also works. :-)

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to write to same line unbuffered wrapping hexdump to stdbuf.
Bash example (requires it due to some read command options):

```
while read -s -n1 k; do printf $k; done | stdbuf -o0 hexdump -e '1/1 "%x"'
```